# How to show multiple selected data from dropdownlist in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I want to show the selected data from multiple drop-down lists in Yii2 without sending it to the controller.
The code I am using is as follows:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'students')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($students, 'studentId', 'name'), ["prompt" => "select...-", 'multiple' => 'multiple', 'onchange' => 'asd(this.value)']) ?>

function asd(vlaue) {
    // $('select').change(function (vlaue) {
    console.log(
        vlaue);
    // })
}
```

When I select the data from the dropdownlist it just shows the same id multiple times in console.

Comment: you can use http://demosbs3.krajee.com/widget-details/select2 and use the `multiple=>true` to use multi-select